# Count the number of active members for each month when only the beginning and expiration dates are known

Tags: sql, count, summary

I have a membership table, a portion of looks like this:

```
   MemberID     StartDate   StopDate
    555753      1/1/2010    1/1/2010
    222458      1/1/2011    12/1/9999
    707222      1/1/2011    12/1/9999
    312643      4/1/2011    1/1/2015
    489112      7/1/2011    12/1/9999
    228466      3/1/2012    12/1/9999
    388456      2/1/2010    8/1/2010
    122345      7/1/2013    2/1/2014
    345677      8/1/2014    12/1/9999
    113884      8/1/2014    12/1/9999
    645322      3/1/2015    12/1/9999
    587432      7/1/2010    12/1/2011
    197534      4/1/2015    12/1/2015
    522345      9/1/2015    12/1/9999
    723891      10/1/2015   12/1/9999
    ...
```

Those expire dates that show 12/1/9999 represent members that have lifetime membership.  There is no correlation between ID numbers and start dates or end dates.  Each member is one record.  I am trying to create a summary table that shows the number of active members for each month starting with Jan 2010 to current.  Each month a random number of members join, while others leave. The months that are recorded are never newer than the current month (to give a limit to the months tracked for lifetime members).

```
             Qty
MonthBucket Members
01-2010      25
02-2010      24
03-2010      25
04-2010      28
05-2010      39
06-2010      35
07-2010      31
08-2010      37
09-2010      42
10-2010      44
11-2010      45
12-2010      41
01-2011      40
02-2011      33
03-2011      37
04-2011      38
05-2011      42
06-2011      45
...
```

I have seen solutions that are great when counting the number of members that join each month, or the number of members lost each month, since those are counting the start and stop dates.  And the next step in count logic would be to simply subtract the number that leave from the number that join.  But how do you account for the implied months between the start and stop dates? I was thinking to do some kind of loop with an if statement comparing whether the month being counted is between the start and end dates, but I am fairly new to SQL programming, are there "do while not EOF" type statements, or a function that would be appropriate?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that You want to print MonthBuckets where there can be no data in membership table for that month. In principle You would have to generate table of buckets. While it can be done on the fly, I would recommend to save it once and use it forewer. This would make writing the query You want really easy.

Make sample data

```
CREATE TABLE membership (
id int,
fromDate date,
toDate date
);

INSERT INTO membership (id, fromDate, toDate)
VALUES
(1, '2014-01-01', '2014-05-10'),
(2, '2014-02-02', '2014-03-10'),
(3, '2014-02-03', '2014-05-10'),
(4, '2014-03-03', '9999-12-31'),
(5, '2014-04-04', '2014-08-08'),
(6, '2015-01-01', '9999-12-31'),
(7, '2015-07-07', '2015-08-08');
```

Now make the buckets table

```
CREATE TABLE monthBucket(
bucketName nvarchar(10),
bucketFirstDay date,
bucketLastDay date 
);

;WITH
  Pass0 as (select 1 as C union all select 1), --2 rows
  Pass1 as (select 1 as C from Pass0 as A, Pass0 as B),--4 rows
  Pass2 as (select 1 as C from Pass1 as A, Pass1 as B),--16 rows
  Pass3 as (select 1 as C from Pass2 as A, Pass2 as B),--256 rows
  Pass4 as (select 1 as C from Pass3 as A, Pass3 as B),--65536 rows
  Tally as (select row_number() over(order by C) as Number from Pass4)
INSERT monthBucket(bucketName, bucketFirstDay)
SELECT  
RIGHT('0000'+CONVERT(nvarchar(10), Y.Number),4) + '-'+ RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(nvarchar(10), M.Number),2),
CONVERT(date, convert(nvarchar(10), Y.Number)+'-'+convert(nvarchar(10),M.Number)+'-01')
FROM Tally as Y
CROSS JOIN Tally as M
WHERE Y.Number < 2100 AND y.Number >= 1980
AND M.Number <= 12

;UPDATE monthBucket SET bucketLastDay = EOMONTH(bucketFirstDay)
--UPDATE monthBucket SET bucketLastDay = DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, bucketFirstDay))
```

This ugly code actually constructs quite simple table:

```
bucketName  bucketFirstDay  bucketLastDay
1980-01     1980-01-01      1980-01-31
1980-02     1980-02-01      1980-02-29
1980-03     1980-03-01      1980-03-31
1980-04     1980-04-01      1980-04-30
1980-05     1980-05-01      1980-05-31
1980-06     1980-06-01      1980-06-30
1980-07     1980-07-01      1980-07-31
1980-08     1980-08-01      1980-08-31
1980-09     1980-09-01      1980-09-30
1980-10     1980-10-01      1980-10-31
...
```

And now we can finally make **the query**

```
SELECT bucketName, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM membership WHERE fromDate <= bucketLastDay)
-(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM membership WHERE toDate < bucketFirstDay)
as membersCount
FROM monthBucket
WHERE bucketLastDay >= (SELECT MIN(fromDate) FROM membership) 
  AND bucketFirstDay <= GETDATE()
ORDER BY bucketFirstDay
```

and the output

```
bucketName  membersCount
2014-01     1
2014-02     3
2014-03     4
2014-04     4
2014-05     4
2014-06     2
2014-07     2
2014-08     2
2014-09     1
2014-10     1
2014-11     1
2014-12     1
2015-01     2
2015-02     2
2015-03     2
2015-04     2
2015-05     2
2015-06     2
2015-07     3
2015-08     3
2015-09     2
2015-10     2
2015-11     2
2015-12     2
```

Answer (score -1):

What if you wanted to retrieve counts in the same fashion but by member type?

```
CREATE TABLE membership (
id int,
fromDate date,
toDate date,
type varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO membership (id, fromDate, toDate, type)
VALUES
(1, '2014-01-01', '2014-05-10','gold'),
(2, '2014-02-02', '2014-03-10','gold'),
(3, '2014-02-03', '2014-05-10','silver'),
(4, '2014-03-03', '9999-12-31','silver'),
(5, '2014-04-04', '2014-08-08','gold'),
(6, '2015-01-01', '9999-12-31','bronze'),
(7, '2015-07-07', '2015-08-08','silver');
```